# Refresh activity when touching Pushup Notification

Tags: java, android, push-notification, notifications

I'm generating a popup notification with alarmmanager. When touching it, it should show a popup, with some details.

When the app is closed and I touch this pushup notification, the right popup is shown.

But when the app is opened, it happens nothing.

How can I force a pushup notification to reload the activity when touching it?

Comment: Can you give more details on your question with code?

Comment: Please attach a [mcve].